# How can i fix Spotipy cache error and use playlists created by other people?

Tags: spotipy

I'm working on a script that creates a markdown table from a Spotify playlist/album link.

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

def get_song_details(uri):
    client_id = 'my client id lives here'
    client_secret = 'my client secret lives here'
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret))
    
    if 'playlist' in uri:
        results = sp.playlist_tracks(uri)
        tracks = results['items']
    elif 'album' in uri:
        album = sp.album(uri)
        tracks = album['tracks']['items']
    else:
        print("Invalid link. Please provide a valid Spotify playlist or album link.")
        return ""

    table = "| Song | Artist | Album | Length |\n| --- | --- | --- | --- |\n"

    for track in tracks:
        song_name = track['track']['name'] if 'track' in track else track['name']
        artist_name = track['track']['artists'][0]['name'] if 'track' in track else track['artists'][0]['name']
        album_name = track['track']['album']['name'] if 'track' in track else album['name']
        duration_ms = track['track']['duration_ms'] if 'track' in track else track['duration_ms']
        duration_min_sec = divmod(duration_ms // 1000, 60)
        length = f"{duration_min_sec[0]:02}:{duration_min_sec[1]:02}"
        table += f"| {song_name} | {artist_name} | {album_name} | {length} |\n"

    return table

uri = input("Enter a Spotify playlist or album link: ")
output_table = get_song_details(uri)
print(output_table)
```

It semi-works, but only for playlists that I've created (not ones made by other people) and albums, and I get a cache error when running:

```
Enter a Spotify playlist or album link: https://open.spotify.com/album/2uhB1KivbFnlkARpbd0Cvu?si=4b461c062dba4e28
Couldn't read cache at: .cache
Couldn't write token to cache at: .cache
| Song | Artist | Album | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 745 sticky | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 02:21 |
| money machine | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 01:54 |
| 800 db cloud | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 02:20 |
| I Need Help Immediately | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 01:21 |
| stupid horse | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 02:01 |
| xXXi_wud_nvrstøp_ÜXXx | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 02:54 |
| ringtone | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 02:23 |
| gecgecgec | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 02:23 |
| hand crushed by a mallet | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 02:06 |
| gec 2 Ü | 100 gecs | 1000 gecs | 03:17 |
```

I was expecting to be able to use any public playlist, not just ones I created, and to not get a cache error.

Edit: I do not get a cache error when running the file from somewhere other than my home directory.

Comment: I got the same _.cach_ problem once. It was caused by a folder called _cach_ in the directory I was running the script from.

Comment: Also, you can not get info of playlists that are not publicly displayed on someone's profile with Client Credentials.